# Lycom PE-115 firware update possible? Otherwise `smartctl` on FreeNAS reports errors

Tags: sata, truenas, firmware, smartctl

I have **Lycom PE-115 SATA 3 2 Port 6Gbps Low Profile PCI-e 2.0 Host Adapter** in my machine running FreeNAS. It seem have some trouble with SMART of SanDisk SSD Plus I connected to it.

I've seen reports people had to do a firmware updates for USB controllers based on similar chip as PE-115 uses, however I cannot find any downloads and instructions how to perform such update. Lycom's webpage is rather poor and doesn't seem to offer firmware updates. Anyone seen this controller in action and maybe had a chance to perform a firmware upgrade?

Comment: Does that HBA even _have_ firmware?

Comment: Good point. But... presence of the same chip in some USB based stuff indicates it probably has. And to be honest - it's hard to imagine SATA chip without any... at least to identify on PCI Express bus.

Answer (score -1):

Marvell MV-9128 chip.
Updated firmware on my Lycom PE-115 (to 2.3.0.1007) with download from station-driers using a FreeDOS USB boot drive.

www.station-drivers.com/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=353&func=fileinfo&id=1572&lang=en

Comment: Be very careful with sites like station-drivers. This particular one is "safe" (the site itself is, maybe not the files on it), but those files are user-submitted with few to no quality checks beyond an optional review process. In general, get your drivers from the manufacturers and never these sites unless you don't care whether the file is safe or not.